# How can I get the recapture probabilities in R (which package to use) ?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a way to estimate the recapture probabilities in my data. Here is an example directly from the package *FSA* in R.

```
library(FSA)    
## First example -- capture histories summarized with capHistSum()
data(CutthroatAL)
ch1 <- capHistSum(CutthroatAL,cols2use=-1)  # ignore first column of fish ID
ex1 <- mrOpen(ch1)
summary(ex1)
summary(ex1,verbose=TRUE)
confint(ex1)
confint(ex1,verbose=TRUE)
```

If you type `summary(ex1,verbose=TRUE)`, you'll have this result

```
# Observables:
#      m   n   R   r  z
# i=1  0  89  89  26 NA
# i=2 22 352 352  96  4
# i=3 94 292 292  51  6
# i=4 41 233 233  46 16
# i=5 58 259 259 100  4
# i=6 99 370 370  99  5
# i=7 91 290 290  44 13
# i=8 52 134 134  13  5
# i=9 18 140   0  NA NA

# Estimates (phi.se includes sampling and individual variability):
#         M M.se     N  N.se   phi phi.se     B  B.se
# i=1    NA   NA    NA    NA 0.411  0.088    NA    NA
# i=2  36.6  6.4 561.1 117.9 0.349  0.045 198.6  48.2
# i=3 127.8 13.4 394.2  44.2 0.370  0.071 526.3 119.7
# i=4 120.7 20.8 672.2 138.8 0.218  0.031 154.1  30.2
# i=5  68.3  4.1 301.0  21.8 0.437  0.041 304.7  25.4
# i=6 117.5  7.3 436.1  30.3 0.451  0.069 357.2  61.2
# i=7 175.1 24.6 553.7  84.3 0.268  0.072 106.9  36.2
# i=8 100.2 24.7 255.3  65.4    NA     NA    NA    NA
# i=9    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA
```

Since, "Observables" is not in a list, I cannot extract automatically the numbers. Is it possible?

I have the same type of dataset, but the output won't show me a probability of recapture. I have an open population. That's why I try to use this package.

Here's a look of the typical dataset:

```
head(CutthroatAL)
#  id y1998 y1999 y2000 y2001 y2002 y2003 y2004 y2005 y2006
# 1  1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
# 2  2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
# 3  3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
# 4  4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
# 5  5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
# 6  6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

I also tried the package *mra* and its *F.cjs.estim()* function. But, I don't have survival information...

I haven't find any function in *RCapture* that allows me to print a capture probability.

I'm trying to find the information pj on page 38 of this book [Handbook of Capture-Recapture Analysis](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hOJxGNERUKgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Handbook%20of%20Capture-Recapture%20Analysis&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIzZeZgN2GyQIVD-BjCh0QZQSr#v=onepage&q=the%20original%20Jolly-Seber&f=false).

I haven't found as well in the *RMark* package.

So how can I estimate recapture probabilities in R?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to capture the "Observable" values in the summary, you can do it the same way the function does. If you look at the source for `FSA:::summary.mrOpen`, you can see that you can grab those values with

```
ex1$df[, c("m", "n", "R", "r", "z")]
```